# Possible to Host LAMP VirtualBox for Internet Site

Tags: networking, virtualbox

Can someone explain briefly, or point me to, how to host a LAMP server on a Linux-based VirtualBox (Oracle) such at the web site on the VB are accessible to the outside world?  The Host itself would be a windows machine that is connected to the internet through cable modem.

I'm already familiar with using VirtualBox as a development LAMP. But, the networking aspects of how this works are what I am asking about.

Comment: The answer to your question is "Yes" (someone does know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can configure VirtualBox Guest Network to work in Bridge mode with your Windows Network Interface, which will allow you to reach your VM from the network Windows computer is in. This means that you can set up routing or bridging between the guest and the rest of your network.

You can read about VirtualBox Networking modes here: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes

Comment: Thanks for this quick and useful reply.  From this information I am further reading that I can use something like DynDNS to get a static IP working with the dynamic IP that will be issued to my host by the ISP.